# Why tack a protocol of NSObject to a protocol implementation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I have been seeing some code around that resembles the following:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
// write some methods.
@end
```

Is there any particular reason why MyProtocol conforms to the NSObject protocol? Isn't that rather redundant in that if you do something such as:

```
id <MyProtocol> foo; // foo here conforms to NSObject AND MyProtocol?
```

Just curious what the logic is.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the reason you would do this is to add the NSObject members (say like retain and release) to your protocol.  Technically you can still send those messages anyways but you will get a compiler warning without it.

Comment: "Technically you can still send those messages anyways" There is no guarantee that the object will understand those messages, if you don't know that it implements the NSObject protocol.

Comment: That's a sound enough answer

Answer (score 35):

When you declare a variable like

```
 id<MyProtocol> var;
```

the Objective-C compiler knows only about the methods in `MyProtocol` and will thus produce a warning if you try to call any of the `NSObject` methods, such as `-retain/-release`, on that instance. Thus, Cocoa defines an `NSObject` protocol that mirrors the `NSObject` class and instance methods. By declaring that `MyProtocol` implements the `NSObject` protocol, you give the compiler a hint that all of the `NSObject` methods will be implemented by an instance that implements `MyProtocol`.

Why is all this necessary? Objective-C allows objects to descend from any root class. In Cocoa, NSObject is the most common, but not the only root class. `NSProxy` is also a root class, for example. Therefore an instance of type `id` does not *necessarily* inherit `NSObject`'s methods.

Comment: Why couldn't you just do "NSObject <Protocol> *variable"? Then you know it's derived from NSObject but also conforms to Protocol, then the compiler won't complain about retain and release.

Comment: Pratically, this is OK (as is casting to (NSObject*) before using any @protocol(NSObject) methods. Unless of course the instance is not, in fact, an NSObject. More importantly, declaring MyProtocol as implementing the NSObject protocol clarifies the intent of the protocol.

Comment: If your protocol doesn't conform to NSObject, I find it preferable to use `id <MyProtocol,NSObject>` instead. One reason is that dynamic typing with `id` allows you to call any method the compiler can find a declaration for (without a warning), rather than just methods inherited from NSObject or declared in your protocol. This can be both dangerous and incredibly useful, depending on whether you're making safe assumptions. :-)

Answer (score 24):

It's also very handy when you have protocols that have `@optional` methods (e.g. "modern" Objective-C 2.0 delegates often use this technique) If you don't include the `NSObject` protocol, you'll get warnings when you try to call `respondsToSelector:` on the object.

Comment: Nice.  This is more relevant than the accepted answer these days as ARC removes the need for anyone to worry about retain/release.

Answer (score 2):

I've never done that in my code, but I could see the advantage to it. If you pass a parameter as `id <SomeProtocol>` you'll need to re-cast it if you want to call any of NSObject's methods on that object.

Answer (score 2):

If you use any of the NSObject protocol methods such as retain, release, class, classname, the compiler will give you warnings unless your Protocol also includes the NSObject protocol.