# handling of TableViewController, possible to go to either of two controllers with one being a UIWebViewController

Tags: ios

Noob at iOS development. This is simply a feasibility question. I wanted to see if it was possible to have a TableViewController and, based upon the type of data that is pushed into the cell, have it do a pushViewController between two different controllers.

Like say for example, we have locations and people that can be returned as search results and we either want to do a pushViewController with either a ProfileController or a LocationController? Would it matter if one of the controllers were a UIWebView?

thx

**EDIT 1**
I guess I'm looking for a way to say if a TableView cell responds to a particular message similar to this question [In Objective-C, given an id, how can I tell what type of object it points to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123485/in-objective-c-given-an-id-how-can-i-tell-what-type-of-object-it-points-to) and determine which UIViewController to push.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "push" another review controller, your table view controller should be embedded in a UINavigationController. Then, there's two ways to handle pushing a new view controller when a row is selected:

Without storyboards (iOS < 5.0), your best opportunity to do things is when `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called on your table view's delegate (typically the table view controller). From there, you can choose where to go based on the `indexPath` that was passed in, create an instance of the view controller you want to go to, and push it onto the navigation controller. For example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIViewController *nextVC;
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        nextVC = [[ProfileController alloc] init];
        // configure nextVC as needed
    } else {
        nextVC = [[LocationController alloc] init];
        // configure nextVC as needed
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES];
}
```

With storyboards (iOS 5.0+), the normal way to do things is to drag a segue in IB from the table cell to the next view controller, and implement your logic to configure the destination view controller based on the selection in `-prepareForSegue:sender:`... but you can't drag multiple segues from the same table cell. Instead, drag segues from the view controller itself, and give them identifiers. Make your choice in `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` as before, but call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` instead of creating the destination view controller yourself. For example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        [self peformSegueWithIdentifier:@"showProfile"];
    } else {
        [self peformSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLocation"];
    }
}
```

If you need to configure the destination view controller based on which table row was tapped, do that in `-prepareForSegue:sender:`.

There's no UIWebViewController... but this would be the same regardless of whether one of your view controllers managed a UIWebView.