# Problems setting up a Navigation Controller using Story Board

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I've set up a Navigation Controller before in previous versions of XCode but I'm using the latest version and trying to set it up using a Story Board. I have  Tab Bar Controller which feeds two forms. The second form has a UITableview which I want to then move to another form when the user has made a selection using the Navigation Controller. I've set out how my relationship looks below.

[image]

The problem seems to be with my relationship set up. I've control clicked from the second form to the Navigation Controller and the pop up offers me a choice from 'Push, Modal or Custom'. I selected 'Push' but when I try to run the code below ir does not work.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
     NSString *tSel = [listContents objectAtIndex:row];

     ConstantRateController *detailController = [[ConstantRateController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConstantRateController_iPhone" bundle:nil];        
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES]
 }
```

I've run the code through debugger and it runs without error but the next form does not show.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like there are three problems:

1. Push segues require that the source view controller be *embedded in* a navigation controller -- instead, you have the source view controller trying to segue *to* a navigation controller.
2. The destination view controller needs to also be in the storyboard.
3. Once you're using storyboards, you generally don't want to follow the pattern for pushing new view controllers from the pre-storyboard world (that is, creating a view controller and pushing it in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`)... doing that duplicates a bunch of the work that storyboards do for you.

Instead:

1. Put your table view controller into a navigation controller, and the navigation controller in the tab view controller. (You can do this with the Editor > Embed In menu, or by dragging them out of the library and dragging "relationship" connections between them.)
2. Put your destination view controller in the storyboard (if it isn't there already) by dragging out a view controller from the library and setting its class to your view controller class (`ConstantRateController`).
3. Drag a push segue from the table view cell to the destination view controller:

[image: drag to create segue]

After all three steps, your storyboard should look like this:

[image]

Finally, in the table view controller, implement the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // test segue.identifier if needed
    MyViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    // set properties of viewController based on selection indexPath
}
```

The segue creates and pushes the view controller; all you need to do is configure it so that its content reflects the table selection which caused the segue. (Note that if you have multiple segues from the table view controller, you should give each a unique identifier in IB and test it in `prepareForSegue:sender:` to configure the appropriate destination view controller.)

---

If you need to support multiple segues out of the table view based on which cell was picked, it's a bit different. Obviously, the storyboard can't know about cells which are populated by your delegate/dataSource, so you can't set up segues from the cell... at least, not in a *dynamic* table.

It sounds like you might be something like a Settings view where you have a static set of cells where each should segue to another view (like some page of settings). In that case, you might want to look at another feature you get from storyboards: *static tables*. If you select the table view (not the table view controller) in IB, the top of the attributes inspector lets you toggle between Dynamic Prototypes and Static Cells -- the former is what I've described above, and the latter lets you create cells and sections and edit their content entirely in IB. With static cells you can make a different segue from each... so you can make a multi-page Settings-like UI pretty much entirely in IB (of course, you'll still need code to do something when switches are flipped and whatnot).

If you need to support multiple segues out of a *dynamic* table, you'll need two things:

1. A different origin for the segues -- you can't have multiple segues coming out of a cell, but you can have multiple segues coming out of the (table) view controller itself.
2. Logic for choosing a segue based on the user's action. Here we're back to `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, but instead of creating the new view controller and pushing it on the navigation controller or presenting it modally, you just call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` on `self`.

There's a little more detail on such in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9733193/957768), and more on storyboard programming practices in general in [Apple's view controllers guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html):

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've followed the instructions and added the above code but when I run it prepareForSegue never gets called. What have I missed?

Comment: Top guesses: 1) Is your `prepareForSegue:sender:` method in the right class? It should be in the view controller that starts the segue (your table view controller). 2) Is the table view controller actually that class? Check the Identity inspector in IB to make sure it's not still a generic `UITableViewController`.

Comment: That's working fine now thank you, it was because I hadn't set the Segue identifier properly. What happens if I want to switch to multiple Segue's, say from my table each selection can go to any one of 10 other forms?

Comment: Talking about multiple segues is a bit complicated for a comment, so I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Usualy when you want to use a Nav Controller, you have to embed it...

> Xcode contains a great way of adding in navigation and tab bar
>   controllers – though it’s a little bit hidden away. First, select the
>   view controller and go to the Editor menu -> Embed In -> Tabbar
>   Controller. Xcode will automatically create our new controller and
>   link up the existing view controller. Again, select the View
>   Controller and this time go to the Editor menu -> Embed In ->
>   Navigation Controller. You’ll see that Xcode inserts the new
>   navigation controller between the tab bar controller and the view
>   controller. Very nice – so far, so good! Your views should look like
>   this…

[from: [http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/]](http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/)

Answer (score 0):

try taking out the "loadView" method and leave the viewDidLoad on the ViewController class you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

you see three segues ('Push, Modal or Custom') and do not see 'root view controller' if you have you Navigation controller CONVERTED from regular ViewController by changing its CUSTOM CLASS. Yes, it called 'Navigation Controller in Storyboad. But its yellow icon is different. It lacks 'Navigation Controller' section in properties and it does NOT work as Navigation Controller. This can be fixed by changing xml source of Storyboard file. Its really confusing  why they call it "embed"..