# Objective-C Determine class of ID in private API

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I'm building a custom ios application (won't be submitted to App store) and I would like to use some private APIs. Since I don't have the source, how do I determine the class of an "id" object defined in the header files.

**For example:**

```
- (void) blahFunction:(id)arg1;
```

How can I find out the expected class object of arg1?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055940/how-do-i-test-which-class-an-object-is-in-objective-c & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123485/in-objective-c-given-an-id-how-can-i-tell-what-type-of-object-it-points-to

Comment: @Mr.UB Thanks, however, those would assume I have the code and can run code inside the function to determine the class of the object. How do I do that if I don't have the source? Protocol or Swift Extension?