# Design to an interface not to an implementation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, design-patterns

I've been reading a book about design patterns for Objective-C and many times I've read things like

```
id <AProtocol> obj;
```

But I think, in pratice, it's not really usable for a simple reason: in iOS you have to manage memory calling release on the object. If you declate it simple with "`id <Protocol>`" and you need to release that obj, XCode is  going to warn you that the "release" method is not in that protocol.

So a more reallistic approach would be

```
NSObject <AProtocol> *obj;
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also an NSObject protocol, so you can simply define:

```
@protocol AProtocol <NSObject>
```

That way the `retain`, `release`, etc. methods of NSObject are visible. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679822/why-tack-a-protocol-of-nsobject-to-a-protocol-implementation).

Comment: You are right. I've just read this from the docs http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `NSObject <AProtocol> *obj` won't compile. But you **can** tell the compiler that your object conforms to the `NSObject` protocol. Just declare:

```
id <NSObject,AProtocol> object;
```

If you think that's too wordy, you can "import" the NSObject protocol into yours when you define it:

```
@protocol AProtocol <NSObject>
// ...
@end
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `NSObject <AProtocol> *obj` compile? I've just got it working. That way you'll be using NSObject as an abstract base class. But the two options you pointed out are at the core of the question. The first `<NSObject, AProtocol>` is a more flexible one in the way that I include the NSObject protocol only in the case its going to require the NSObject methods and not wrap it every time as the second option. I think I got it.

Comment: Agree, `NSObject<AProtocol> *obj` compiles just fine, as does `id<NSObject,AProtocol> obj`.

Comment: +1 for the `id <NSObject,AProtocol> object;` declaration. I didn't knew that I can specify several protocols here, and this is a very natural solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can also make `AProtocol` itself conform to the `NSObject` protocol:

```
@protocol AProtocol <NSObject>
…
@end
```

By doing that, the compiler won’t emit a warning for:

```
id <AProtocol> obj;
…
[obj release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the most specific one you can. Use NSObject * if you **know** it is an instance
of NSObject and not, say, NSProxy.

Use `NSView <AProtocol>*` if you know the instance is a subclass of NSView.

However this has nothing to do with -release. If you infact need to protocol to define the release method, that is, it makes no sense for an object to implement this interface if it doesn't also implement the NSObject protocol, include the NSObject protocol in the definition of AProtocol as @Bavarious demonstrates.