# Adding category method to NSObject, but getting warnings because it's not in the <NSObject> protocol when I call it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, protocols, categories

(I found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679822/why-tack-a-protocol-of-nsobject-to-a-protocol-implementation) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944009/why-must-i-make-a-protocol-like-this) discussing the idea, but I didn't see a solution for my problem.)

I added this convenience method as a category to NSObject. (I've added other methods, so I'm still interested in an answer even if you disagree with this particular convenience method.)

```
@implementation NSObject (MyCategory)
- (void)performInvocationOnMainThread:(NSInvocation *)invocation waitUntilDone:(BOOL)waitForMainThread;
@end
```

Then I have a protocol I defined:

```
@protocol MyDelegateProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)myDelegateProtocolMethod;
@end
```

Then I declare the delegate as a property of my class that implements said protocol.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyDelegateProtocol> delegate;
```

But when I try to call the NSObject method I added in my category like so

```
NSInvocation *invocation = [self.delegate invocationForSelector:@selector(someSelector:withArg:)];
```

I get this warning

```
'-performInvocationOnMainThread:waitUntilDone:' not found in protocol(s)
```

If I cast my delegate as `(NSObject *)` then I don't get the warning. What am I doing wrong? It didn't seem like I could (or should?) add methods to an existing protocol without creating a "sub protocol" and using it from then on. (Which kind of defeats the point of adding methods to NSObject in mind.)

```
NSInvocation *invocation = [(NSObject *)self.delegate invocationForSelector:@selector(someSelector:withArg:)];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your category extends the `NSObject` **class**, not the `NSObject` **protocol**. While the class now has the method, it's not defined as part of the protocol, hence the warning.

That's why typecasting to the `NSObject *` pointer type works; you're casting to the `NSObject` class type, rather than something like `id<NSObject>` which means an arbitrary Objective-C object that conforms to the `NSObject` protocol.

You'll have to make an intermediate protocol (or "sub protocol") that extends the `NSObject` protocol:

```
@protocol ExtendedNSObject <NSObject>
- (void)performInvocationOnMainThread:(NSInvocation *)invocation waitUntilDone:(BOOL)waitForMainThread;
@end
```

Then have your delegate protocol extend that one instead:

```
@protocol MyDelegateProtocol <ExtendedNSObject>
- (void)myDelegateProtocolMethod;
@end
```

*If I'm not wrong*, you can keep the existing `NSObject (MyCategory)` implementation, and they'll play nice together.

Comment: Plus, categories usually define additional implementation, which protocols have nothing to do with.

Answer (score 3):

when pass/expect this type, qualify it like so:

```
- (void)race:(NSObject<MyDelegateProtocol>*)arg;
```