# <NSObject> in protocols

Tags: objective-c, protocols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why tack a protocol of NSObject to a protocol implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679822/why-tack-a-protocol-of-nsobject-to-a-protocol-implementation)

Does this mean `Foo` is conforming to `NSObject`'s protocol? Does `Foo` have to implement `NSObject`'s protocol methods like when other classes conform to protocols?

```
@protocol Foo <NSObject>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just ensures that you add the `NSObject` members to your protocol, please check out this post:

[Why tack a protocol of NSObject to a protocol implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679822/why-tack-a-protocol-of-nsobject-to-a-protocol-implementation)

Comment: Thanks for the link! So let's say the `Foo` protocol didn't conform to `NSObject` and my class `ClassA` conformed to `Foo` and imported `Foundation`. Would the methods in `ClassA` still be able to access methods from `NSObject` since it imported `Foundation`?

Comment: Protocols don't that much influence on their conforming class.  What would happen if `Foo` didn't conform to `<NSObject>`, is that you would be limited to calling only the methods you defined in `Foo's` protocol declaration.  No -respondsToSelector, no -retain, no -release, without compiler warnings.