# Protocol conformation error Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

In **DataProvider.h**

```
@protocol NewDataProviderProtocol 

- (void)fetchNewData;

@end
```

In **SomeClass**

```
#import DataProvider.h
@interface SomeClass :NSObject <NewDataProviderProtocol>

@end
```

When I try to make SomeClass conform to **NewDataProviderProtocol** it says,

`No type or protocol named 'NewDataProviderProtocol'`

It's weird since I already imported header DataProvider.h in which the protocol is declared.

So I forward declare the **NewDataProviderProtocol** before interface of **SomeClass** but xcode warns

```
Cannot find definition for **NewDataProviderProtocol**
```

What's the reason and the workaround for this?

Comment: Do you import SomeClass.h into DataProvider.h, too? It sounds like a include-cycle which leads to one undeclared identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. Reason

Likely you have a include cycle, because you import SomeClass.h into DataProvider.h, too. This leads to an undeclared identifier.

Why is it that way? Let's have an example:

```
// Foo.h
#import "Bar.h"
@interface Foo : NSObject 
…// Do something with Bar 
@end


// Bar.h
#import "Foo.h"
@interface Bar : NSObject 
…// Do something with Foo 
@end
```

If you compile, let's say Foo.h, the precompiler will expand this:

He gets …:

```
// Foo.h
#import "Bar.h"
@interface Foo : NSObject 
…// Do something with Bar 
@end
```

… imports Bar.h (And strips comments … But let's focus on the main topic.) …

```
// Foo.h
   // Bar.h
   #import "Foo.h"
   @interface Bar : NSObject 
   …// Do something with Foo 
   @end

@interface Foo : NSObject 
…// Do something with Bar 
@end
```

Foo.h will not be imported again, because it is already imported. Finally:

```
   // Bar.h
   @interface Bar : NSObject 
   …// Do something with Foo 
   @end

@interface Foo : NSObject 
…// Do something with Bar 
@end
```

This is quite clear: If A relies on B and B relies on A, it is impossible for a serial data stream as a file is, to have A ahead of B and B ahead of A at the same time. (Files are not subjects of the theory of relativity.)

B. Solution

In most cases you should give your code a hierarchy. (For many reasons. Having no import problems is one of the least important.) I. e. in your code an import of SomeClass.h into DataProvider.h looks strange.

Having such a problem is a code smell. Try to isolate and repair the reason for that. Do not move code pieces into different location to find a pace, where it works. This is code lottery.

C. Structure

Usually you have a class that expects others to conform to a protocol. Let's have an example:

```
// We declare the protocol here, because the class below expects from other classes to conform to the protocol.

@protocol DataSoure
…
@end

@interface Aggregator : NSObject 
- (void)addDataSource:(id<DataSource>)dataSource 
// We are using a protocol, because we do not want to restrict data sources to be subclass of a specific class.
// Therefore in this .h there cannot be an import of that – likely unknown - class
@end
```

SomeClass, that conforms to the protocol

```
#import "Aggregator.h"

@interface SomeClass:NSObject<DataSource>
…
@end
```

Comment: Thanx a ton. Now it's clear. That was the reason. :)

Comment: Especially when factoring code out, it has happened 10923801239 times to me, to forget to remove an import …

Comment: Yea that happend to me cuz I used concrete class previously and tried to seperate it into an abstraction.

Comment: Now this raises another question. Where do we declare the protocols? In the class being served - SomeClass.h or class that serves the DataProvider.h ------or separate it out altogether in new file? Whats the best practice?

Comment: Usually you in the class that expects others to conform to the protocol. This is, because this class can never rely on other – potentially unknown – classes. I'll add code to my A.

Comment: Now I think It's better to separate it out in different .h file like DataProviderProtocol.h. If we do so if we need to make new concrete class that has different implementation of fetchData like LocalDataProvider.h It would make more sense if we import protocol declaration from DataProviderProtocol.h rather than DataProvider.h Dont you think? The client and server both needs abstraction.

Comment: The comment above was before you put the C. Segment in your answer. That makes sense too. @Amin. Thanks for helping me out with this :)

Comment: You can put it in a separate .h, too. Esp. this makes sense, if you have a bundle of classes expecting protocol conformance. (DataAggregator, DataSelector, DataCompressor …)

Answer (score 0):

Two things to change:

Change definition like this:

```
@protocol NewDataProviderProtocol <NSObject>    
- (void)fetchNewData;    
@end
```

Why? [Why tack a protocol of NSObject to a protocol implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679822/why-tack-a-protocol-of-nsobject-to-a-protocol-implementation)

Import `DataProvider` in `SomeClass.m` only. You can always create an extension of `SomeClass` inside implementation file where you can bind the protocol to conform a particular class.

```
@interface SomeClass ()<NewDataProviderProtocol>

@end
```

Why? It's the best practice. And to overcome forward class declaration errors. E.g. [Objective-C: Forward Class Declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191487/objective-c-forward-class-declaration)

Comment: Shifting protocol conformance to .m seem to work. But I can't figure why? And why should a protocol conform to <NSObject> too? Also I always conform the UITableViewDataSource in .h files why is not possible for custom protocol?

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha Please review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679822/why-tack-a-protocol-of-nsobject-to-a-protocol-implementation for why your protocol should extend the `NSObject` protocol.

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha And moving to the .m file worked for you because your .m file is probably importing the `DataProvider.h` file.

Comment: But since I imported DataProvider.h in SomeClass.h before declaring the interface of SomeClass shouldn't it work there as well?

Comment: It will work normally. But I am pointing to future issues (?), its not necessary but its a good practice :)

Comment: It is not a good practice, because what you have in the .h and the .m is a question of what you want to have public resp. privat. It is not a question of what can work-around bad code structure.